# Is it true the Rebbe said you have to have trust when checking For kashrut?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, chassidic-rebbe, yoreh-deah

BH

Have been checking for Kashrus recently a lot and one guy told me that the Rebbe said there is a point in Kashrus that you have to trust in Hashem that the food is kosher. Is this true and if yes where does he say this?

Comment: Do you mean the Lubavitcher Rebbe? If yes please [edit] for clarity